# EF does not add object even in the table object

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
    public ServiceResult Add(TPost value)
    {
        try
        {
            Table.Add(CastFromCreateViewModel(value));

            foreach (var item in Table)
            {

            }

            DataHelper.SaveChanges();

            return ServiceResult.NewServiceResult(true,null);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ServiceResult.NewServiceResult(false, ex);
        }
    }
```

the Table comes from the child:

```
    protected override DbSet<Data.Product> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return DataHelper.db.Products;
        }
    }
```

ande the caster is implemented in the child too:

```
    public override Product CastFromCreateViewModel(ProductCreateViewModel obj)
    {
        return obj;
    }
```

now after adding the object to Table obj, even in the next foreach, the result is not including the new object. No error and no exceptions!

Comment: did you inspect the `Table` object before `foreach`?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh before foreach or before add?

Comment: after `Add` , see if the object was actually added to your `Table`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh i think the foreach should do this!

Comment: Could you try to do the SaveChanges before the foreach ?

Comment: @Atlasmaybe nothing changed.

Comment: Could you show ````DataHelper```` class code?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. There's way too much indirection here, the problem could be anywhere.

Comment: ok, thanks. i wll do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is related to this code "DataHelper.db" .
I've had this problem before, and the reason was that I had written the wrong code and i had a new context on saveChange

Comment: yes you are right, i was saving changes on another context!